# JavaScript in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android

Is it possible to use JavaScript in Android?? if so, how? Please provide some examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Androids browser engine WebKit can run JavaScript. So you create a HTML file with embedded JS or some other referenced file and use it.

Comment: It's not java script. It's javascript, a language that has nothing whatsoever to do with java (in fact, C++ is more closely related to java than javascript is).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am way late to the party here, but I had this exact need.  iOS 7 now includes JavaScriptCore
natively and it is really easy to use (despite limited documentation).  The problem is that
I didn't want to use it unless I could also use something similar on Android.  So I created the [AndroidJSCore project](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore).  It allows you to use your JavaScript code natively in Android without requiring a bulky WebView and injection.  You can also seamlessly make asynchronous
calls between Java and Javascript.

**Update 27 Mar 17:** AndroidJSCore has been deprecated in favor of [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore).  LiquidCore is based on V8 rather than JavascriptCore, but works essentially same.  See the [documentation on using LiquidCore as a raw Javascript engine](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore/wiki/LiquidCore-as-a-Native-Javascript-Engine).

From the documentation:

... to get started, you need to create a JavaScript `JSContext`.  The execution of JS code
occurs within this context, and separate contexts are isolated virtual machines which
do not interact with each other.

```
JSContext context = new JSContext();
```

This context is itself a JavaScript object.  And as such, you can get and set its properties.
Since this is the global JavaScript object, these properties will be in the top-level
context for all subsequent code in the environment.

```
context.property("a", 5);
JSValue aValue = context.property("a");
double a = aValue.toNumber();
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".#");
System.out.println(df.format(a)); // 5.0
```

You can also run JavaScript code in the context:

```
context.evaluateScript("a = 10");
JSValue newAValue = context.property("a");
System.out.println(df.format(newAValue.toNumber())); // 10.0
String script =
    "function factorial(x) { var f = 1; for(; x > 1; x--) f *= x; return f; }\n" +
    "var fact_a = factorial(a);\n";
context.evaluateScript(script);
JSValue fact_a = context.property("fact_a");
System.out.println(df.format(fact_a.toNumber())); // 3628800.0
```

You can also write functions in Java, but expose them to JavaScript:

```
JSFunction factorial = new JSFunction(context,"factorial") {
    public Integer factorial(Integer x) {
        int factorial = 1;
        for (; x > 1; x--) {
            factorial *= x;
        }
        return factorial;
    }
};
```

This creates a JavaScript function that will call the Java method `factorial` when
called from JavaScript.  It can then be passed to the JavaScript VM:

```
context.property("factorial", factorial);
context.evaluateScript("var f = factorial(10);")
JSValue f = context.property("f");
System.out.println(df.format(f.toNumber())); // 3628800.0
```

Comment: I just gave AndroidJSCore a try, and it seems to work quite well! I noticed however that it runs only on 32 bit machines. Are you planning on adding 64 bit support? Since most new phones are 64 bit, it is pretty much a showstopper...

Comment: Yes.  64-bit support is planned for the 2.1 release.  It turns out that the compiler in the NDK is based on GCC 4.9.2.  It has a bug related to atomics that JavaScriptCore depends on.  I am working on a GCC 4.9.3 build which reportedly fixes the problem.  Once I can get it to work, I will release it.  Should be soon.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thanks, I'm really looking forward to it.

Comment: [AndroidJSCore 2.1](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore/releases/tag/2.1) is now released, including 64-bit support.  As an added bonus, I've extended support back to Jellybean, so 94% of devices are now covered.

Comment: Great! I'll try it out in a few days!

Comment: I have javascript function to be executed from Android activity. I want to pass a java object as an argument to this method and Map a java object with a variable in that function. Please suggest how to achieve this using  AndroidJSCore library.

Comment: @AndEngine: This can be easily done with AndroidJSCore.  `JSContext context = new JSContext(); context.evaluateScript(my_JS_code); JSObject myJSFunc = JSContext.property("myGlobalFunctionName").toObject(); JSValue retVal = myJSFunc.callAsFunction(null,new Object[] { javaArg1, javaArg2, ... }) ;` Click through the link for detailed examples.

Comment: @EricLange myJSFunc.callAsFunction() 2nd argument seems to be wrong. it expects an array of JSValue. i am using the latest version. Is there any option to add dependency through Maven repo in android studio

Comment: @AndEngine try `new JSValue[] { ... }` instead.

Comment: @EricLange Could you edit your answer to include LiquidCore

Comment: @EricLange: I have a javascript file in local res folder and all I need to do is access the file and call one method in it called encrypt(a, b) and pass 2 parameters from my activity for the calculation. Can you please tell how to achieve that

Comment: @AnimeshJena: see my reply to AndEngine above.

Comment: @EricLange: That is not working in LiquidCore. Mostly myJSFunc.callAsFunction

Comment: @AnimeshJena please post the issue at https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore/issues.  This is not the place for debugging.

Comment: @EricLange Hi, i am trying to use Liquidcorejs to run js natively in android.
The problem i am facing is i am unable to use any libraries in the script (say XMLHttpRequest) in my script. How can i solve this problem ? .
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like making a native app using Javascript? I know there are tools like [Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) that let you make native apps using web tools/languages.

You could also make Web Apps. There are loads of resources and tutorials out there for that. Just search "Android Web App tutorial" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, just create a wrap up code that points to html page and includes your javascript and css.

There are different libraries that can help you with this:

- http://www.phonegap.com/
- http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/
- http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this for posterity but React Native is a great solution in this space. You can write a complete app in JS using native views under the hood, or embed a JS component inside an existing Java app. https://reactnative.dev/